# Recovery in new ledger nano s

Tags: blockchain, ether, wallets, bitcoin, ledger-nano-s

Let us say that we create 3 bitcoin address and 4 ethereum address. This means that we have 3 public private key for bitcoin and 4 public private key for ether.

After recovery using the 24 word seed, How the new ledger nano s knows that I have used 3 address in bitcoin and 4 address in ethereum.

I wonder how this happens. Could you please help me to understand ?

Comment: My guess would be that it scans the blockchain and looks to see how many addresses from the address sequences have been used. As far as I can tell, this is how JAXX works.

Comment: @lungj  but the number of address is infinite right ?

Comment: It’s bounded by the number of unique Ethereum addresses. But even if it weren’t, it’s also bounded by the number of transactions you can make.

Comment: Even if the system assumed you never need more than a trillion addresses (enough for about 50 transactions per second for the average person’s lifetime), it would have to check no more than 40 addresses to figure out where to it left off (per chain).

Comment: Unable to understand your latest comment

Comment: Using binary search, you can search a (sorted) space in log time. To find the last used address in a 2^256 bit linear search space (which we can assume since we can generate the n-th address the wallet generates directly), you perform at most 256 searches. Divide the space in two. Address used yet? No? Divide the first half of the space in two and search again. It’s like how you can look up a word in a dictionary by flipping back and forth until you find the right word. In a dictionary with 512 (2^9) pages, binary search means you need to check at most 9 pages to find your word.

Comment: Repeat this process once for each chain you’re using (bitcoin, ethereum, etc.)

Comment: Will this work if we create some n unused address and start using n+1th address..

Comment: Not using the scheme I described. Also, you can’t “create“ an unused address. Addresses aren’t created on the block chain. Every address already exists. You mean skip some elements in the sequence of generated keys/addresses.

Comment: Then how the ledger nano s works perfectly still remains a question...

Comment: If I previously had an account called 'rocket funds', how would this appear in a newly restored ledger or can I only access the funds by manually creating the custom accounts again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIP44 defines the [address gap limit](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#address-gap-limit) to be 20. Which means during recovery, as when importing your master public key in a wallet for monitoring, the software looks 20 addresses ahead of the last used address.

If functioning normally, the software should only derive a new public address if the last one hasn't seen any transaction. You can't force the Ledger Nano app to create a new address. From BIP44 again:

> Wallet software should warn when the user is trying to exceed the gap limit on an external chain by generating a new address.

This is to avoid the problem of having to potentially re-generate and scan an arbitrary number or public addresses.

So basically the recovery procedure is:

- Derivate 20 keys from the master public key
- Scan all adresses
- Take the last used one (child X) and generate keys up to X+20
- Scan the new addresses
- Rinse and repeat last 2 steps until nothing new shows up

There is a bit longer and general explanation of the system [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54660/how-do-hierarchical-deterministic-wallets-work-transaction-wise).